# Uncaught Error: Missing query for request id: reqId:0

Tags: google-visualization

Trying to push data to google Charts Api from PHP using the example at:

https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization&hl=es#chart_editor

My code returns:

```
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","status":"ok","reqId":"reqId:0","table":{"cols":[{"id":"col_Fecha","label":"Fecha","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"col_Importe","label":"Importe","pattern":"#0.###############","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2014-02-10 13:47:47"},{"v":"885.79"}]}]}});
```

Which is valid JSON format.

Still I get: 'Uncaught Error: Missing query for request id: reqId:0'

And I just can't find the problem. Any help?

Comment: Should it be "reqId":"0" , not "reqId":"reqId:0" ?

Comment: The "reqId" parameter should return whatever the query sent as the "reqId" (this helps match queries to results when multiple queries are performed).

Comment: Thanks both of you! That was the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [David A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255964/david-a) and [asgallant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613559/asgallant) pointed out in the comments my request was erroneous an should have been "reqId":"0" , not "reqId":"reqId:0"